# How do I delete a column header in QTP?

Tags: qtp, test-data, data-driven, uft

I had a QTP Data Table and named some of my columns.

I decided I didn't need one of my columns for my test, but it won't let me remove a column name once its set. I can't remove the column header and now my column names are all messed up. Is there a way to completely delete a table permanently, not just the column header?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? You did not accept it, so maybe there is something more about that you would need to know? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete a column/columns:

```
datatable.GetSheet(MySheetName).DeleteParameter ColumnName
```

Delete "CatNo" cloumn from "cats info" sheet.

```
datatable.GetSheet("cats info").DeleteParameter "CatNo"
```

Also.
As far as I know you can always open it with Excel and to it "manualy".